# React Native : View does not bound to the right

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've been dabbling with some react native code and found that my view does not have a right boundary in both android and iOS renders. So when I add a horizontal margin, the view displays margin only on the left like this.

[image: Snapshot of Render]

I am also attaching my code and styles to guide me on where I would have gone wrong.

Login.js

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {View,ToolbarAndroid,Text, Image, StatusBar,TextInput, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles.js'

class LogIn extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {hostName: '', userName: '', password: ''}
  }

  onButtonPress() {
    this.props.onSubmit && this.props.onSubmit(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Image style={styles.container} source={images.background}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor="#00EF6C00" translucent={true}/>
        <View style={styles.logocontainer}>
          <FitImage source={images.logo} resizeMode="contain" resizeMethod="scale" style= {{width: 300,position: 'absolute', left: 50, height: 100}}/>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.comp_container}>
          <TextInput placeholder="Host Name" style={{height: 40}} onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({hostName: text})}/>
          <TextInput placeholder="User Name" style={{height: 40}} onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({userName: text})}/>
          <TextInput placeholder="Password" style={{height: 40}} onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password: text})}/>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)} style={{height: 40, flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <Text style={{flex: 1}}> Submit </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Image>
    )
  }

}

LogIn.propTypes = {
  onSubmit: React.PropTypes.func,
}
export default LogIn;
```

Also Please find the attached stylesheet for further information on style

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  toolbar: {
    backgroundColor: '#EF6C00',
    height: 56,
    elevation: 3,
  },
  textInput: {
    borderRadius: 20,
    borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
    height: 40,
  },
  button: {
    height: 40,
  },
  logocontainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  comp_container: {
    flex: 2,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  }
});

export default styles
```

**Edit:** It is almost palpable that the problem should be with react-native unable to decide where the view boundary is. So instead of wrapping within the view, it decides to extent it. I also would love to get to know of any tools which can help me debug the UI issues, like the uiautomationviewer for android.

Answer (score 1):

You do not specify `width` nor `resizeMode` in background image so it overflows screen. By default `alignItems` is `stretch`, `TouchableOpacity` fills container on horizontal and also overflows screen.